# Ошибка запроса MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT
  *,
count(commentstomedicalfacilities.idCommentsToMedicalFacilities) AS count_comments,
CASE WHEN Count IS NULL THEN 0 END AS CountLikes
FROM
  medicalfacilities
aleft outer join
  `likes`
ON
  likes.IdNote = a.idMedicalFacilities
left outer join
  commentstomedicalfacilities
ON
  commentstomedicalfacilities.CommentsToMedicalFacilitiesIdMedical = a.idMedicalFacilities
  AND
  likes.LikeType = 1
WHERE
  a.MedicalFacilitiesName LIKE '%com%'
GROUP BY
  a.idMedicalFacilities
```

Выдает ошибку вида:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'outer join `likes` ON likes.IdNote = a.idMedicalFacilities left outer join comme' at line 1

Не могу понять, почему ругается

Comment: medicalfacilities aleft

Answer (score 2):

> medicalfacilities aleft outer join

Внимательно прочитайте. aleft != left